# AVC denied Flutter X python

Tags: flutter

W/1.raster(12904): type=1400 audit(0.0:466252): avc: denied { search } for name="battery" dev="sysfs" ino=6933 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c191,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_batteryinfo:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

Comment: Please add more information to the question. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask